# Python GUI builder (Page) setup combobox options

Tags: python, ttk

Hi I have trying to configure the Combobox in python using ttk library, but unfortunately it is not letting me to add the values

```
self.qType = ttk.Combobox(top)
    self.qType.place(relx=0.69, rely=0.09, relheight=0.04, relwidth=0.22)
    self.qType.configure(textvariable=dnsGui_support.combobox)
    self.qType.configure(width=137)
    self.qType.configure(takefocus="")
```

dnsGui_support.combobox is in sepearte file

```
global combobox
combobox = StringVar("")
combobox.set("AA")
```

I have tried combobox['values'] = ('AA', 'MX')
but that gives me error stringvar instance has no attribute **setitem**
If I run my program without setting the value it run fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.qType = ttk.Combobox(top)
self.qType.place(relx=0.69, rely=0.09, relheight=0.04, relwidth=0.22)
self.value_list = ['MX', 'AA', 'CNAME']
self.qType.configure(values=self.value_list)
self.qType.configure(textvariable=dnsGui_support.combobox)
self.qType.configure(width=137)
self.qType.configure(takefocus="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling this on the wrong object.

It's a bit confusing that you named a `StringVar` object `combobox`, and a `Combobox` object `qtype`. But it's the `Combobox` object that has a list of strings that you can set. A `StringVar` just has a single string—in this case, the current selection of the `Combobox`.

The error message may be a little opaque. The reason it says `StringVar instance has no attribute __setitem__` is that `x[key] = value` actually calls `x.__setitem__(key, value)`, so if the type of `x` (`StringVar` in your case) has no such method, that's what the error says.

I don't know if you can see a `Combobox`'s values using the dict-style syntax or not (the support for that is a big haphazard…). If it doesn't work, you presumably need to `configure` it, or possibly even `configure` the underlying `Listbox`. But, either way, it's the `Combobox` that you need to operate on.

Comment: i have never used Python Gui builder. I made a Gui using page by drag and droping object and it builds the code for me. I'm very confused how to use it. I'll try to work on actual object qType and let you know if I find a Solution. Thanks for your insightful info.

Comment: @Reboot I've never used PAGE either. Is it even still being maintained? Its last news item mention adding support for Python 3.2, which is about 6 years out of date.

Comment: I have no idea, I have just found about PAGE a couple of days ago.

Comment: I fount the solution